# Javascript regex for url detect and split

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the below urls :

```
https://comanage.example.edu/sp
https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp
https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp
https://myapp.example.com/sp
```

For these urls, I need to define a function that can detect them as URLs and then replace the https:// and sp path from them. Basically, I just need the hostname only.For ex, like below

```
https://comanage.example.edu/sp      ->comanage.example.edu
https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp       ->wiki.cs.example.org
https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp ->intranet.math.example.edu
https://myapp.example.com/sp         ->myapp.example.com
```

For non urls, the function should detect and do not replace for them. Like below,

```
nonurl.example.com -> ***no replacement***
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for above,I do not have much knowledge on usage of regex.

Comment: Why not just parse the URL and extract what you need? i.e. if there's no protocol, don't do anything. Doesn't seem like a problem that regex is the solution.

Comment: Instead of regex, you can just do `new URL(url)` and then extract `.host` from it. Wrap it in a try-catch block to handle non-URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API)

```js
[ 'https://comanage.example.edu/sp'
, 'https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp'
, 'https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp'
, 'https://myapp.example.com/sp' 
]
.forEach( url => console.log( new URL(url).host ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const urls = [
  'https://comanage.example.edu/sp',
  'https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp',
  'https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp',
  'https://myapp.example.com/sp',
  'nonurl.example.com',
];
const pattern = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/;

console.log(urls.map(v=> v.match(pattern) ? v.match(pattern)[1] : null));
```

Comment: `v.match(pattern) ? v.match(pattern)[1] : null` can be simplified as `v.match(pattern)?.[1] ?? null`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `^https?:\/\/` should work here pretty easily for you.  We can use that to replace `http://` and `https://` at the beginning of any string with an empty string

In the pattern the `^` symbol denotes the beginning of the string.  This means if `http://` somehow appeared in the middle of the string, it would **not** match that since it must be at the beginning

The `?` marks the previous character as optional. In the pattern the `s` is optional to that `http` and `https` can be found.

The `\/` is there simply because the slashes have to be escaped.

```js
const urls = [
  'https://comanage.example.edu/sp',
  'https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp',
  'https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp',
  'https://myapp.example.com/sp',
  'nonurl.example.com',
];

const pattern = /^https?:\/\//i;

urls.forEach(u => {
  console.log(u, '-->', u.replace(pattern, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with the help of `RegEx`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const urls = [
  'https://comanage.example.edu/sp',
  'https://wiki.cs.example.org/sp',
  'https://intranet.math.example.edu/sp',
  'https://myapp.example.com/sp'
];

const hostNames = urls.map(url => url.replace(/^https:\/\/([\w.-]+)\/sp$/, '$1'))

console.log(hostNames);
```

RegEx explanation **:**

```
/^https:\/\/([\w.-]+)\/sp$/
```

`^`: Matches beginning of the string.
`https:\/\/`: Matches the literal string `https://`. The backslashes (`\`) are used to escape the forward slashes (`/`) since they are special characters in regular expressions.
`([\w.-]+)`: This is a capturing group that matches one or more occurrences of word characters (`\w`), dots (`.`), or hyphens (`-`). The + quantifier means that it should match one or more characters.
`\/sp`: Matches the literal string `/sp`. Again, the backslash is used to escape the forward slash.
`$`: Matches at the end of the string.